# Html.Dropdown list events in MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, dom-events, html-helper

Can anyone please tell me about -

How can I handle Html.DropDown control's events in MVC View?
Can I handle it using scripts?
And how to know about the selected item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use jquery you can handle events something like this:

```
$("#IdOfYourSelectList").change(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
});
```

This creates a handler for the change event. If you want to bind a handler to some other event you just replace change with whatever event you want to handle.

The same goes for any html element.

Answer (score 1):

You should use jQuery and attach a handler for the change event in your document.ready

```
$('#mySelect').change(function(e) {
var val = $(this).val();
});
```